# Cut out region in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have a large building map imported from a DWG file and I want to only keep one region:

[image]

Is there a way to do this not by masking the outter region, but removing all shapes outside my region.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the map is vectorial:

- Make a rectangle around the area to be preserved
- Select all
- Use the **Shape Builder Tool** + <kbd>Alt</kbd>
- Click the paths outside the rectangle to delete them

[image]
[image]

---

Or:

- Make a rectangle around the area to be preserved
- Select all
- From the **Pathfinder Panel** press **Divide**

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I do, but this could ba very slow process. Is there any straightforward solution ?

Comment: Answer updated.